# matlab function variable definition

Tags: matlab, function

In Matlab, I want to get the variables from the workspace for the function . But I did not do it.
For example; the function is:

```
function  Y  = objfun(x)
Y = 20+x(1).^2 + 2*x(2).^2 -15*x(3);
end
```

gives me the following problem when I run the function

```
>> objfun
Not enough input arguments.

Error in objfun (line 5)
Y = 20+x(1).^2 + 2*x(2).^2 -15*x(3);
```

x variable is exist in workspace like x= [4 5 7] and I don't want to write it inside of function. so what shall I do.

Maybe it is very east question for you but I don't know and I trid make it.
could you help me?

Comment: enter  `objfun(x)` instead of `objfun`

Comment: Yes it works but why doesn't work the run button

Comment: Because then you're giving it no input argument

Comment: So is it not possible without write the x inside function. either I must write it inside the function or use objfun(x) in command window. isn't it?

Comment: There is a way but you ***should not*** use it which is using global variables

Comment: Thank you for answers Serdar

Comment: There is another better way which is mentioned in the dupe target. (The second way)

Comment: ok. it can be good example for me. I will try make it like the examples which you sent. Thank you for helping again

Comment: Sorry Serdar, Actually you said "you should not use it" so I really can't understand exactly your idea and I could not ask again to not bore you. Now I understand from your angry reaction it is possible. Thank you again and forgive me

Comment: It's okay to ask, and no it didn't make me angry. If you want to know why I made that recommendation, read [this answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51946-systematic-do-not-use-global-don-t-use-eval#answer_63393) and [the third paragraph of this answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51946-systematic-do-not-use-global-don-t-use-eval#answer_63374) to get an idea

Comment: ok. I will read. Thank you for your all advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab (or Octave) you can use [scripts or functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html).

If you create script called `objfun`, you have what you are looking for. Just call it using `objfun` and it will use workspace variable `x`. The script is saved as `objfun.m`.

Functions are different. They can have arguments, but these arguments are local variables (only available within the function).

If you define a function, you must call it with the arguments.

Comment: thank you Jgrocha, So can I use global variables or not?

Comment: Yes, you can use global variables. But functions with internal variables are much safer to use.